# Securing WebApi using open ID connect

Tags: asp.net-web-api, configuration, native, openid-connect

I have having a problem when trying to secure a Web API service using OpenId connect and ADFS 2016.

I have a mobile native client which successfully gets an access, refresh and Id token from ADFS after entering their credentials into the presented logon page.

However when I use that token to access my simple web api method it always presents the logon page

Here is my Startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions();
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);



            var openIdConnectAuthenticationOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "**<myclientid>**",
                MetadataAddress = "https://**<myFullyQualifiedDomainName>**/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "my.client.native://callback",
                RedirectUri = "my.client.native://callback",
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("*** RedirectToIdentityProvider");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    MessageReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("*** MessageReceived");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("*** SecurityTokenReceived");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("*** SecurityTokenValidated");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("*** AuthorizationCodeReceived");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("*** AuthenticationFailed");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }

                }
            };

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConnectAuthenticationOptions);


        }
    }
```

When I make a call to my Web API GET method I am seeing the the open id options notification for RedirectToIdentifyProvider being hit in the debugger, none of the other notifications are hit. I assume at this point it has decided that the logon page should be presented again. So what I get in the the response to my HTTP GET is the html of the ADFS logon page.

Has anyone got any ideas about how to get this to work with a native client attempting to access a webapi service method? As far as I can tell this is correct. My problem is that most of the exaples out there are for a web page accessing Web Api. I'm not sure about setting the authentication type to use cookies. Is that correct?

Also should I be using app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication for a native client, or should I be using a different OWIN middleware.

Any input would be appreciated as I have spent well over a week trying to figure out what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After another days investigation I solved the problem, it seems that using the **app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication** is not the correct thing to use for native adfs clients. I believe this should be used for passive clients like a web page.

Instead the following code should be used for active clients like mobile or desktop apps

```
    app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
        new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataEndpoint = https://AdfsServerFullyQualifiedDomainName>/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = "<web api replying party url configured in ADFS>"
                    },

                });
```